# How to judge if a point is in the interior of a closed curve or not?

Tags: geometry, regions

For example:

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2)}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2)}};
trig=JoinedCurve[Line[pts], CurveClosed -> True];
```

Then `trig` is a closed triangle. If I have a point `p={a,b}`, how can I judge if `p` is in the interior of the triangle `trig`?

Comment: Does "in the triangle" mean "Inside the triangle" or "In the perimeter of ..."?

Comment: sorry, I mean "inside"